# 10 inch blade instead of 12 in

Tags: table-saw

I could use some insight, please.

I have a Craftsman 220 table saw. Trying to find a 12in blade with a 5/8s hole is an arduous task.

Can I use my 10 in blades with this saw?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one safely mount an 8" blade in a 10" saw if the arbor sizes are compatible?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/can-one-safely-mount-an-8-blade-in-a-10-saw-if-the-arbor-sizes-are-compatible)

Comment: Yes some 10" blades have knock outs for 5/8" check on line for 12" blades. The 12" blades with 5/8 holes are common on line but not necessarily cheap for a high quality one. A properly set up RAS will out perform most miter saws

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Considerations for using smaller diameter blades on table saw?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/considerations-for-using-smaller-diameter-blades-on-table-saw)

Comment: See also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/168732/101382